# How to pass a pointer to an exported Rcpp function?

Tags: r, function, pointers, rcpp

I'm wrapping some c++ code with Rcpp for an R package and the function I want to export takes an input which is a pointer to a double, like so:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int foo(double * x){
  // do stuff with x

  return 0;
}
```

The pointer needs to point to the first element of a matrix/numeric data frame (defined in R). Any idea of how I can pass this kind of pointer to the function from R or how I can modify the input parameters to interface more easily with R?

I have tried getting the memory location of R objects using tracemem and passing this into the function, however the output of tracemem is a string not a pointer. I've also tried passing the whole matrix into the function (changing the parameter type) and defining a pointer to its first element, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: There are worked examples in package [RcppDE](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppde) for doing this in the context of optimization, see the demos or vignette.  In a more general setting you likely want 'external pointers' which R supports, and Rcpp covers as `XPtr`,  There are lots of example here in older questions, at the Rcpp Gallery, and elsewhere.

Comment: I think I misread your question earlier today.  You are not asking about a function pointer (my bad) but just a function with `*double`.  So the easiest is too look at the basic Rcpp documentation and copy the setup for a (copy by value) `double` (which is actually a pointer because we use `SEXP` internally, but that is for another day...) and have that function call your actual function.  In short, [add a layer of indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering).

Comment: That makes sense! I am still a bit confused about SEXP variables, but found that modifying the function to take as input a vector of doubles and just creating a pointer within the function to that vector works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel could you please give a simple example on how to do this? How can one pass data from r to Rcpp function using pointers

Comment: @onyambu I provide two earlier comments.  What you ask is addressed there, in the documentation for Rcpp (including its ten viignettes and contributed sites such as the Rcpp Galltery) as well as in general documentation about R (and its interface to C and C++).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks for your time and response. Been spending hours on this but still unable to solve. Went through most of the viignettes and the Rcpp gallery, yet still havent found an example of passing an R object by pointer which will in turn modify the object. Probably i am thinking/searching wrongly. I will still keep on reading more. Seems i am missing something. Thanks

Comment: You are missing that an SEXP is already a pointer and can take a vector of anything.  You don't need pointer.  If you still insist, look at `.C()` which has been there for decades and takes pointers (but is discouraged).  All this is well documented.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have been using `.C()` function. though that needs me to maintain my code in `C`. With Rcpp, i was hoping not to rewrite whole C functions. Some of the C functions take in pointers, I am still stuck on these ones.  I still have alot to learn about Rcpp. I do appreciate for your response.  Will look on how to pass in data from R to Cpp functions that take in pointers

Comment: Do you understand the basic duality of, say, `double*` and `double[]`?  Do you understand that inside a `std::vector<double>` is in fact a contiguous chunk of memory which, if you insist, you could align to `double*`.  There are interface here that work _automatically_ and that have been used for what may literally millions of compilation.  If you still insist on doing it different be my guest but your insistence creates a lot of unnecessary extra work for one person: you.  Ask yourself it is worh it.

Comment: PS  And no, using `.C()` does not mean your source files has to in C. Works for C++ too. Is still discouraged because `.Call()` gives you richer semantics.